# TEXT_NODE: returns ONLY text?

Tags: javascript, dom, textnode

I'm using JavaScript in order to extract all text from a DOM object.  My algorithm goes over the DOM object itself and it's descendants, if the node is a TEXT_NODE type than accumulates it's nodeValue.
For some weird reason I also get things like:

```
#hdr-editions a { text-decoration:none; }
#cnn_hdr-editionS { text-align:left;clear:both; }
#cnn_hdr-editionS a { text-decoration:none;font-size:10px;top:7px;line-height:12px;font-weight:bold; }
#hdr-prompt-text b { display:inline-block;margin:0 0 0 20px; }
#hdr-editions li { padding:0 10px; }
```

How do I filter this?  Do I need to use something else? I want ONLY text.

Answer (score 8):

From the looks of things, you're also collecting the text from `<style>` elements.  You might want to run a check for those:

```
var ignore = { "STYLE":0, "SCRIPT":0, "NOSCRIPT":0, "IFRAME":0, "OBJECT":0 }

if (element.tagName in ignore)
    continue;
```

You can add any other elements to the object map to ignore them.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but I still get weird stuff like: UAstring=navigator.userAgent;
if (UAstring.indexOf('iPad')>-1){$('makeHPLink').hide();}
function cnnMakeHP() {

<!--.cnn_sectt4cntnt{overflow: visible;}.cnnOpin { position:absolute;top:-18px;right:7px; }.cnnOpin a.realmLink {font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;color:#004276;}-->
Are there anymore tags I should ignore?

Comment: This is what I did:
 if (domObj.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
   if (!(domObj.tagName in ignore))
    acc += domObj.nodeValue;    
}

Comment: @eve: you need the ignore check first - text nodes don't have tag names so you need to check the tag name earlier, before descending to and iterating over the element's child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to skip over `style` elements.

In your loop, you could do this...

```
if (element.tagName == 'STYLE') {
   continue;
}
```

You also probably want to skip over `script`, `textarea`, etc.

Comment: `element.tagName` returns an uppercase string, I made the same mistake :-)

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I always forget things like that :)

Answer (score 0):

This is text as far as the DOM is concerned. You'll have to filter out (skip) `<script>` and `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer added after reading OP's comments to Andy's excellent answer]

The problem is that you see the text nodes inside elements whose content is normally not rendered by browsers - such as STYLE and SCRIPT tags.

When scan the DOM tree, using depth-first search I assume, your scan should skip over **the content of such tags**.

For example - a recursive depth-first DOM tree walker might look like this:

```
function walker(domObject, extractorCallback) {
    if (domObject == null) return; // fail fast
    extractorCallback(domObject);
    if (domObject.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) return;
    var childs = domObject.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++)
        walker(childs[i]);
}

var textvalue = "":
walker(document, function(node) { 
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        textvalue += node.nodeValue;
});
```

In such a case, if your walker encounters tags that you know you won't like to see their content, you should just skip going into that part of the tree. So `walker()` will have to be adapted as thus:

```
var ignore = { "STYLE":0, "SCRIPT":0, "NOSCRIPT":0, "IFRAME":0, "OBJECT":0 }

function walker(domObject, extractorCallback) {
    if (domObject == null) return; // fail fast
    extractorCallback(domObject);
    if (domObject.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) return;

    if (domObject.tagName in ignore) return; // <--- HERE

    var childs = domObject.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++)
        walker(childs[i]);
}
```

That way, if we see a tag that you don't like, we simply skip it and all its children, and your extractor will never be exposed to the text nodes inside such tags.